# How to disable processor cores in MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra v10.12.3?

Tags: macos, mac

I need to disable one of the cores in my machine for application testing purposes. I'm running macOS High Sierra v10.12.3

Note: A 10 year old answer can be found in…
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071116183942199
…but it doesn't work with 10.12.3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired [CPUSetter](https://www.whatroute.net/cpusetter.html)? I can't say I've used it, but it is updated and appears to meet your needs.